# How can I write a windows batch file that opens a command prompt and executes a command?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a .cmd file that opens the command line at a location relative to the .cmd file itself, and then executes something like this:

`someapp start ../../config.js`

How can I do this?

Comment: Also consider `bash`, though you will have to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look, CMD is your friend: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

> Examples:
>
> Run a program and pass a Filename parameter: CMD /c write.exe
>   c:\docs\sample.txt
>
> Run a program and pass a Long Filename: CMD /c write.exe "c:\sample
>   documents\sample.txt"
>
> Spaces in Program Path: CMD /c ""c:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\Office\Winword.exe""
>
> Spaces in Program Path + parameters: CMD /c ""c:\Program
>   Files\demo.cmd"" Parameter1 Param2
>
> Spaces in Program Path + parameters with spaces: CMD /k ""c:\batch
>   files\demo.cmd" "Parameter 1 with space" "Parameter2 with space""
>
> Launch Demo1 and then Launch Demo2: CMD /c ""c:\Program
>   Files\demo1.cmd" & "c:\Program Files\demo2.cmd""

Comment: I can open the command line and cd to a new location, but whats the syntax for then executing a second command? `cmd.exe /k "cd node_modules\.bin"` ... then what?

Comment: See the ampersand in the final example in duDE's answer.

Comment: @AFH: Thank you, the ampersand is necessary to concantenate several commands. Maybe I've misunderstood the question but I think the point is "/c" parameter: cmd /c notepad C:/tmp/text.txt

Comment: I'm trying this and it isn't working, whilst it works if I execute the commands manually into a command prompt.. `cmd.exe /k ""cd node_modules\.bin" & "karma start  ../../karma.conf.js""`

Comment: I've tryed as well by creating the file test.cmd with this one line inside and it works...

Comment: it was the double quotes- they werent needed - thanks!

Comment: cant upvote dont have enough rep :|

Comment: NP at all, you are welcome, glad to help! :)